# How to differentiate between BTC transactions and BRC20 transactions on a blockchain?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, json-rpc, python, ordinals

How to differentiate between BTC transactions and BRC20 transactions on a blockchain using the RCP interface?

This is a transaction record that contains BRC20 tokens which I found on a blockchain explorer.

When I using the RPC to scan blocks and retrieve transaction records like this one, how can I use Python3 to determine whether the transaction is a BRC20 or BTC transaction?

```json
{
    "hash": "331d02db3d6ee0cffae9052be5799bd7754c6ebb2020e422058b73334c59bf85",
    "ver": 2,
    "vin_sz": 1,
    "vout_sz": 2,
    "size": 359,
    "weight": 734,
    "fee": 7360,
    "relayed_by": "0.0.0.0",
    "lock_time": 0,
    "tx_index": 4705820269244017,
    "double_spend": false,
    "time": 1682913851,
    "block_index": 787738,
    "block_height": 787738,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "sequence": 4294967293,
            "witness": "03405d88c3c66893b950a42d3672f3009a9f15e674f248a1d1c435609440b91e426598d9505752c560b24ba6261f1b3c7e997941006c9ead7b0378ca7c92c65519418320117f692257b2331233b5705ce9c682be8719ff1b2b64cbca290bd6faeb54423eac061b237bd58701750063036f7264010118746578742f706c61696e3b636861727365743d7574662d3800357b2270223a226272632d3230222c226f70223a226d696e74222c227469636b223a2266726565222c22616d74223a2231303030227d6821c0117f692257b2331233b5705ce9c682be8719ff1b2b64cbca290bd6faeb54423e",
            "script": "",
            "index": 0,
            "prev_out": {
                "addr": "bc1pejeuynu5edq5fvfa8elpkem6zuzvrvqx20zundhpyuy3h3y8wumslwyd5h",
                "n": 0,
                "script": "5120ccb3c24f94cb4144b13d3e7e1b677a1704c1b00653c5c9b6e127091bc4877737",
                "spending_outpoints": [
                    {
                        "n": 0,
                        "tx_index": 4705820269244017
                    }
                ],
                "spent": true,
                "tx_index": 6896182349770388,
                "type": 0,
                "value": 10000
            }
        }
    ],
    "out": [
        {
            "type": 0,
            "spent": false,
            "value": 546,
            "spending_outpoints": [],
            "n": 0,
            "tx_index": 4705820269244017,
            "script": "51208873ed390476c5c7b6c825bae7eca675a46bc200cc7a82354b0debec19f83abc",
            "addr": "bc1p3pe76wgywmzu0dkgykaw0m9xwkjxhssqe3agyd2tph47cx0c827qd4yq9x"
        },
        {
            "type": 0,
            "spent": true,
            "value": 2094,
            "spending_outpoints": [
                {
                    "tx_index": 1274202281123575,
                    "n": 0
                }
            ],
            "n": 1,
            "tx_index": 4705820269244017,
            "script": "0014ea410b1701aeaa64dbf721cd55fce1231f2144a3",
            "addr": "bc1qafqsk9cp464xfklhy8x4tl8pyv0jz39rhhh0s7"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to analyze ? Witness component 1 , Witness component 2, Witness component 3.

If I want a complete analysis, what should I do.

The analogy is as follows:

```json
{
  "p": "brc-20",
  "op": "mint",
  "tick": "free",
  "amt": "1000"
}
```

```
ID 331d02db3d6ee0cffae9052be5799bd7754c6ebb2020e422058b73334c59bf85i0
Length 53
Type text/plain;charset=utf-8
Timestamp 01 May 2023 12:04:11
Block height 787738
Size 133
Standard: brc-20
Operation: mint
Token: free
Amount: 1000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **How to differentiate between BTC transactions and BRC20 transactions**

Well, you can't because they are not disjoint sets, all BRC-20 transactions are also BTC transactions.

You identify BTC transactions that are also BRC-20 transactions in two stages:

1. Does it contain an Ordinals Inscription
2. Does the inscription contain a BRC-20 operation.

You look in the penultimate witness component for the Ordinals signature ("ord" etc)

You look in the inscription for JSON text content that matches the BRC-20 patterns.

In your example, just converting your "witness" from hexadecimal to ASCII produces

... `ord` ... `text/plain;charset=utf-8` ... `{"p":"brc-20","op":"mint","tick":"free","amt":"1000"}`

But parsing it properly would be more reliable.

---

#### Parsing the Witness data

| Hexadecimal data | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `03` | There are three witness components |
| `40` | Length of first component is 0x40 = 64 bytes |
| `5d88c3c66893b950` `a42d3672f3009a9f` `15e674f248a1d1c4` `35609440b91e4265` `98d9505752c560b2` `4ba6261f1b3c7e99` `7941006c9ead7b03` `78ca7c92c6551941` | Witness component 1 |
| `83` | Length of second component is 0x83 = 131 bytes |
| `20117f692257b233` `1233b5705ce9c682` `be8719ff1b2b64cb` `ca290bd6faeb5442` `3eac061b237bd587` `01750063036f7264` `010118746578742f` `706c61696e3b6368` `61727365743d7574` `662d3800357b2270` `223a226272632d32` `30222c226f70223a` `226d696e74222c22` `7469636b223a2266` `726565222c22616d` `74223a2231303030` `227d68` | Witness component 2 |
| `21` | Length of witness component 3 is 0x21 = 33 bytes |
| `c0117f692257b233` `1233b5705ce9c682` `be8719ff1b2b64cb` `ca290bd6faeb5442` `3e` | Witness component 3 |

Different input types (for output types P2WPKH, P2WSH, P2TR etc) have different things in the witness lists. This can be seen in answers to [What are the scriptPubKey, scriptSig, redeem script and witness for the various output types?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/107872/13866)

#### Parsing the penultimate witness component (component 2)

The [Ordinals Inscription documentation](https://docs.ordinals.com/inscriptions.html) says

> A text inscription containing the string "Hello, world!" is serialized
> as follows:
>
> ```
> OP_FALSE 
> OP_IF
>    OP_PUSH "ord"
>    OP_PUSH 1
>    OP_PUSH "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
>    OP_PUSH 0   
>    OP_PUSH "Hello, world!"
> OP_ENDIF
> ```

Here's what I came up with treating component 2 as bitcoin script:

| Hexadecimal data | Normal Meaning | Commentary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `20` | Push the next 0x20 (32) bytes onto the stack |  |
| `117f692257b23312` `33b5705ce9c682be` `8719ff1b2b64cbca` `290bd6faeb54423e` | Pushed data |  |
| `ac` | OP_CHECKSIG | *(Note that nothing after this ends up affecting the final stack value and so has no effect on normal Bitcoin nodes. For them, the following might as well not exist)* |
| `06` | Push the next 0x06 (6) bytes onto the stack |  |
| `1b237bd58701` | Pushed data |  |
| `75` | OP_DROP | *(throws away data just pushed onto stack - presumably private data of inscriber?)* |
| `00` | OP_FALSE | *(This is the start of the Ordinals Inscription serialization)* |
| `63` | OP_IF | *(Since the previous operation added FALSE to the stack, script execution on normal bitcoin nodes will skip everything up to OP_ENDIF. The rest still has to look like valid script though.)* |
| `03` | Push the next 0x03 (3) bytes onto the stack |  |
| `6f7264` | Pushed data = ASCII `ord` |  |
| `01` | Push the next 0x01 (1) byte onto the stack |  |
| `01` | Pushed data has value `1` | *(Ordinals indication that MIME type follows)* |
| `18` | Push the next 0x18 (24) bytes onto the stack |  |
| `746578742f706c61` `696e3b6368617273` `65743d7574662d38` | Pushed data = ASCII `text/plain;` `charset=utf-8` | *(I am surprised "application/json" wasn't used)* |
| `00` | OP_0: Push integer `0` onto the stack | *(Ordinals indication that inscription data follows)* |
| `35` | Push the next 0x35 (53) bytes onto the stack |  |
| `7b2270223a226272` `632d3230222c226f` `70223a226d696e74` `222c227469636b22` `3a2266726565222c` `22616d74223a2231` `303030227d` | Pushed data = ASCII `{` `"p":"brc-20",` `"op":"mint",` `"tick":"free",` `"amt":"1000"` `}` | *(This is an inscription in JSON format (despite prior MIME type) that contains a BRC-20 token minting operation.)* |
| `68` | OP_ENDIF | *(in this case, end of Ordinals Inscription)* |

Obviously you are looking for the script elements that are prescribed for Ordinals inscriptions. the last but one item above is the actual inscription. It can be parsed as JSON to give the BRC-20 data structure.  Obviously `p`'s value, `brc-20`, is what you are searching for in the JSON data.

---

Related

- [What are the scriptPubKey, scriptSig, redeem script and witness for the various output types?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/107872/13866)

Comment: Thanks, you said it so well. I understand now.
But what if there are more than one in the witness? Just like this:
I see multiple strings in witness that are used, split : 



    "inputs": [
        {
            "sequence": 4294967293,
            "witness": "03405d88c3c03405d88c3c, 03405d88c3c,03405d88c3c",
            "script": "",
            "index": 0,

Comment: `"witness": "03405d88c3c03405d88c3c, 03405d88c3c,03405d88c3c",` looks like a bug in whatever blockchain explorer you are using. I suggest you work with the raw binary data, or at least raw hex, rather than this, or any other, blockchain explorer's JSON interpretation

Comment: Thanks, You're a genius. 
How to analyze ? Witness component 1 , Witness component 2, Witness component 3. 
If I want a complete analysis, what should I do.
The input field here is too small, I added the case to the question.

Comment: That's an interesting follow-on question but not one I have an answer to at the moment. It is something I will probably spend time on eventually.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: @Mashaji See "Related" link I added to bottom of answer. Answers to that related question indicate what witness components are expected, and their meaning, for each different type of transaction input.